# ffmpeg with Videoconverter.js MTS to .mp4 conversion issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been scratching my head over this issue and going through dozens of google search results to find a solution to this, but no luck. I've got an issue when trying to convert MTS to mp4 with Videoconverter.js, which uses ffmpeg commands for converting video. I have installed ffmpeg, and run successfully .webm to .mp4 conversions. I've changed the Videoconverter.js file that specifies files to be used in the terminal, and I'm using commands from tutorials for MTS conversions (I've tried multiple options already), but to no avail. I keep getting "File not found", although it certainly is there, next to .webm which I converted before successfully. 
Anyone know what this might be?

```
Worker has received command
Received command: -i 00091.MTS -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 15M -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 192k output.mp4.          Processing with 268435456 bits.
ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  9 2014 20:24:32 with emcc (Emscripten GCC-like replacement) 1.12.0 (commit  6960d2296299e96d43e694806f5d35799ef8d39c)
  configuration: --cc=emcc --prefix=/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist --extra-cflags='-I/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/include -v' --enable-cross-compile --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --cpu=generic --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-asm --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-network --disable-hwaccels --disable-parsers --disable-bsfs --disable-debug --disable-protocols --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --enable-protocol=file --enable-libvpx --enable-gpl --extra-libs='/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/lib/libx264.a /Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/lib/libvpx.a'
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
00091.MTS: No such file or directory
Finished processing (took 140ms)
```

Comment: I made some progress I think, but now I get "missing function: madvise".

Comment: I know I've had this exact same problem with FFmpeg but I fail to recall the solution right now. I do remember that, in my case, the file was definitely there. Are you certain that A) You have permission to read the file; B) that the file is seekable; C) that the file is real and not, e.g., a pipe or symlink; D) that the file is bigger than 0 bytes?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've sorted it out without the use of videoconverter.js. From command line tools, the process is straight forward once the ffmpeg is correctly installed and linked. Then I used mac command extension to wrap the script. Sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've completed the conversion using command line tools instead. Videoconverter.js might have been the issue here, most likely.

Comment: Could you tell us how you did this? I'm running into the same issue, and I'm unsure how to compile in Windows 8 to get this issue fixed. I need to compile a list of PNG files to MP4, so not sure what options to use. or how to get it built. Thanks.

Comment: I guess my question should be - what configuration flags did you use?

Comment: I ditched the videoconverter.js altogether and used shellscript instead. I've created a loop going over all my files. In the example, I've added watermark, intro, outro and sound. `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "$i" -i ../watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=1680:860' -map 1:0 -qscale:v 1 -to 30 "${i%MTS}mpg"
cat "${i%MTS}mpg" ../conc/outro.mpg > intermediate_outro.mpg
cat ../conc/intro.mpg intermediate_outro.mpg  > intermediate_all.mpg
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 2 "${i%MTS}mp4"ffmpeg -i "$i" -i ../track.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 "../outputFiles/${i%mp4}mp4"`